# How to remove white background of UIImageView?

Tags: iphone, uiimageview

I am making an application in which i am trying to add an image of a circle

but when i am adding the image ,it comes with white background..

How to remove the  white background.

Even i have set background color to clear and even opaque property to NO but it seems,has

has no effect.

Kindly provide some valid solution.

Thanks,

Comment: Does your image have a transparent background? Or is it white too?

Comment: It might be your image issue. Please check your image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for an image to have a transparent background the image itself must have a transparent background.  Then when loading the image from file into an `UIImageView` the background will also be transparent.

Try using the image I've provided:

[image: Circle]

Comment: A way to check without programming is to open the file in the Preview application. The transparent parts of the image should show as the background color. You can use the preferences to change the background  color for additional confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

user should take an image having no background color...then it will work properly